# How to remove padding in the mat-select-panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select, mat-form-field

How do I remove this padding for the ma-select-panel.

[image: Highlight the padding]

I have tried using

```
ng:deep .mdc-menu-surface.mat-mdc-select-panel {
padding: 0px !important;
}
```

But I just couldn't remove it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: BAAAAD: 
 ::ng-deep .mat-mdc-select-panel {
      padding: 0 !important;
    }
GOOOD:
ideally namespace to body tag. but let's be less destructive now and add class to component as below.

 <mat-select  panelClass="myClass">

and add this to root styles:
.myClass {
  &.mat-mdc-select-panel {
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that a mat-select create a cdk-overlay. This means that the "panel" is "outside" the component -really is outside the whole app-.

This is the reason you need makes the .css was in any way "global".

I generally use the styles.css (not the component.css)

```
div.mat-mdc-select-panel
{
    padding:0;
}
```

If you don't want this .css is applied to all the mat-select in your application is when you use the property `panelClass` this allow you write

```
<mat-select panelClass="custom-select">
   ...
</mat-select>
```

And use

```
.custom-select.mat-mdc-select-panel {
  padding:0;
}
```

There're another option that it's use

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

But I don't like so much because this makes that all the .css in your component is applied to all the applicacion -it's the same that include the component.css in your styles.css

Comment: Thank you, this worked.
Just had to add `!important` in the CSS.

Comment: @sahus, you should avoid use `!important`, It's better makes more "specific" the .css ( (have more selecters)  Use the developer tools in your navigator (F12), check what css definition it's more especific. Well, I do it and I think that the .css should be `div.custom-select.mat-mdc-select-panel` (see the "div")